# Attractiveness of Coulomb potential from Peskin-Schroeder textbook

Tags: charge, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, coulombs-law, carrier-particles

On page 125 chapter 4.8 of Peskin & Schroeder "An Introduction To Quantum Field Theory" there's a sort of argument that should prove that in the non-relativistic limit of QED like charges repel and opposite charges attract. However, there's a minus sign that seems to appear out of nowhere.

In the $e^-e^-$ case the textbook says the leading order contribution is:$$ e^-e^- \rightarrow e^-e^- \implies i\mathcal{M} = (-ie)^2 \bar{u}(p') \gamma^\mu u(p) \frac{-i g_{\mu\nu}}{(p'-p)^2} \bar{u}(k') \gamma^\nu
u(k)  $$
$$
= +ie^2 \bar{u}(p') \gamma^\mu u(p) \frac{g_{\mu\nu}}{(p'-p)^2} \bar{u}(k') \gamma^\nu
u(k), \tag{4.133}$$

and then states that in the non-relativistic limit
$$
\bar{u}(p')\gamma^0u(p) = u^\dagger(p')u(p) \simeq +2m \xi'^\dagger\xi
$$

while the other terms  $\bar{u}(p')\gamma^iu(p)$ are negligible so we get
$$
i\mathcal{M} = \frac{+ie^2}{-|\mathbf{p}'-\mathbf{p}|^2} (+2m \xi'^\dagger\xi)_p (+2m \xi'^\dagger\xi)_k = - \frac{ie^2}{|\mathbf{p}'-\mathbf{p}|^2} (+2m \xi'^\dagger\xi)_p (+2m \xi'^\dagger\xi)_k.\tag{4.134}
$$
And since we have a minus sign this is a repulsive Yukawa potential.
Then the book deals with the $e^-e^+$ case arguing that there will be an extra minus sign making this case an attractive potential. However I really don't understand where this extra minus sign should be coming from, my calculations are exactly the same as the previous case and the book doesn't show them explicitly. My working out is:

$$ e^-e^+ \rightarrow e^-e^+ \implies i\mathcal{M} = (-ie)^2 \bar{u}(p') \gamma^\mu u(p) \frac{-i g_{\mu\nu}}{(p'-p)^2} \bar{v}(k) \gamma^\nu
v(k')  $$
$$
= +ie^2 \bar{u}(p') \gamma^\mu u(p) \frac{g_{\mu\nu}}{(p'-p)^2} \bar{v}(k) \gamma^\nu
v(k') $$

$$ \bar{v}(k) \gamma^0 v(k') = v^\dagger (k)v(k') = +2m\xi^\dagger\xi'
$$

so everything turns out the same as before:

$$
i\mathcal{M} = \frac{+ie^2}{-|\mathbf{p}'-\mathbf{p}|^2} (+2m \xi'^\dagger\xi)_p (+2m \xi^\dagger\xi')_k = - \frac{ie^2}{|\mathbf{p}'-\mathbf{p}|^2} (+2m \xi'^\dagger\xi)_p (+2m \xi^\dagger\xi')_k.
$$

What am I missing? What happens that makes the first and the second case different?

Comment: Right after 4.136 they mention that the factor of -1 is the same as the one that appeared in the calculation of the Yukawa potential, which arises from the reordering of the fermion operators